# JNI-calling Java from c++ how to use "import javax.jms.*"?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I do not have much experience in JNI but for one Project I have to use JNI- calling java methods from c++.

Now the problem is my java file is using  import javax.jms.*(Message,Topic...etc) and whenever any method calls it(.java) need argument type Method Message message to pass.
Example: in java file **public void ABC(Message message)** How I can call this method from c++ as I do not have jms in C++ I can not get Message message so what will be the procedure?

I checked online and it says have to use CMS(As I am using ActiveMQ).is there any other way?

How JNI will work in this case??

Thank you!

Comment: Forget about JNI for a second. How would you construct an instance of Message in Java?

Comment: You will have to construct `Java` object inside `C++` and pass it as argument. Take a look here for slightly different sample (https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo061). In here, you can see how to pass data from `C++` based `std::map` to `Java` based `java.util.HashMap`. You will have to do similar thing in your code. You will have to construct `Message` by calling its constructor/methods, and eventually pass it as argument of your function.

Comment: @Botje Message is an interface so no need to initialize it will be directly passing as an argument

Comment: If you want to call a method with a `Message` argument, you need to have an object that satisfies that interface. If you have it: great, then what is the problem? If you don't: do you have a plan for creating one?